# »2014 spielt Deutschland gegen Portugal, {das · der · die} zu stark ist.«

Tags: gender, place-name

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   *[Gender of country names without articles](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/10836/5437)*

---

> 2014 spielt Deutschland gegen Portugal, {das · der · die} zu stark ist.

Portugal ist ein Land und *Land* sächlich. Ist diese Kenntnis genug, um den Relativsatz richtig zu bauen?

Wenn man einen Deutschkurs besucht, lernt man »Ausnahmen« für die Länder, die mit Artikel geschrieben werden müssen. Das heißt

> die Türkei, die Schweiz, der Irak, der Libanon, die Vereinigten Staaten, usw.

Aber mir wurde nicht gesagt welche und ob alle anderen Länder ein sächliches Geschlecht haben.

Also:

> 2014 spielt Deutschland gegen Portugal, das zu stark ist.

Comment: +1 Sehr gute Frage. Ich überlege gerade, wieso es überhaupt Ausnahmen für manche Länder gibt und nicht alle *sächlich* sind. Wann und wo wurde das festgelegt? Und wieso? Über solche scheinbar banalen Dinge denkt man als Muttersprachler nie nach =)

Comment: 'Portugal ist ein Land und Land sächlich.' Ist Portugal nicht auch ein Staat (m.)? Eine Nation (w.)? Eine Gebietskörperschaft, eine Gegend, eine Entität, ein Konstrukt, eine Republik, ein Problemfall, eine Utopie, ...? Dieser Versuch eine Metakategorie zu finden scheitert daran, dass es immer viele Metakategorien gibt, deren Geschlecht auseinanderfallen kann (antwortete der Mann, das GL-Mitglied, die Nervperson). Der Irak ist übrigens auch ein Land, oder die Mongolei.

Comment: Das Land heißt übrigens "der Libanon", aber nur einen Buchstaben kann ich nicht editieren ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Das Geschlecht des Wortes "[Portugal](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Portugal)" ist sächlich. Also meine ich, dass Du recht hast, und man es so sagen könnte

> 2014 spielt Deutschland gegen Portugal, das zu stark ist.

Comment: Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass die Annahme korrekt ist: Geographische Namen, die normalerweise ohne Artikel geschrieben werden, sind sachlich.

Comment: Allerdings würde man hier eher "welches zu stark ist" sagen.

Comment: Ist schon ein bisschen her die Antwort, aber ich habe einen starken Drang, hier den Plural zu verwenden, weil ich sofort an die Mannschaft denke. Zwar hört sich `2014 spielt Deutschland gegen Portugal, die zu stark sind.` komisch an, aber der Satz an sich ist auch sehr hölzern. Ganz klar würde ich aber `2014 spielt Deutschland gegen Portugal. Die sind einfach zu stark!` sagen und nicht `2014 spielt Deutschland gegen Portugal. Das/es ist einfach zu stark!` Obwohl Portugal vielleicht neutrum ist, stellt sich der Bezug zu "das/es" bei mir nicht ein.