# Gender of country names without articles

Tags: gender

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *[»2014 spielt Deutschland gegen Portugal, {das · der · die} zu stark ist.«](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9285/5437)*

There are some country names with article, like *der Iran*, *die Schweiz*, *die Niederlande*.

But what is the gender of the country names without articles?

For example, what pronoun to use in the following case:

> Frankreich hat mit Sanktionen gedroht. **Er/Sie/Es(?)** hat alle Bankkonten gesperrt.

My intuition says me that countries generally are feminine, when they have no article, am I right?

Comment: Zumindest bei Frankreich kann man argumentieren, daß _Reich_ sächlich ist, und daher Frankreich auch.

Comment: Reiche (Frank**reich**, Öster**reich**) und Länder (Deutsch**land**, Finn**land**) sind auf jeden Fall sächlich.

Answer (score 10):

c.p. is correct that countries without an article are neuter. But I would like to add that an example like yours would still sound weird ("ES hat alle Bankkonten gesperrt"). In general, pronouns are avoided with countries.

Comment: In many publications the entity of the state would be replaced by the entity of the government when it comes to being in charge of decisions, like `Frankreich hat mit Sanktionen gedroht. Die französische Regierung [or whatever entity] hat alle Bankkonten gesperrt.`

Comment: Exactly - it would be very unusual to refer to a country using a personal pronoun. When it comes to actively doing something, the common solution is to name the entity responsible for the decision (`Die Regierung`, `Das Finanzministerium`, `Die Bankenaufsicht`), or naming the person politically responsible for the move.

Comment: @teylyn: Exactly not. Dass man die genaue Organisation benennen kann sagt gar nichts darüber aus, ob man es nicht auch lassen kann. Frankreich verhängte erst Sanktionen, dann erklärte es den Krieg. Die Regierung verhängte Sanktionen, dann erklärte sie den Krieg. President Hollande verhängte erst Sanktionen, dann erklärte er den Krieg. Finde das Muster.

Answer (score 7):

Das Geschlecht der meisten Staaten ist neutral: Das schöne Deutschland, das offizielle Italien, das alte China.

Es bestehen die bekannten Ausnahmen, bei denen *die* verwendet wird, entweder wegen des Plurals:

**die** Bahamas, die Komoren, die Niederlande, die Philippinen, die Salomonen, die Seychellen, die USA, die Vereinigten Arabischen Emirate

... oder wegen des Geschlechts:

**die** Dominikanische Republik, die Mongolei, die Schweiz, die Slowakei, die Türkei, die Ukraine, die Zentralafrikanische Republik

**der** Irak, der Iran, der Gambia (seltener), der Jemen, der Kongo, der Libanon, der Niger, der Oman, der Senegal, der Sudan, der Tschad, der Vatikan.

Ganz allgemein geht die Tendenz dazu den Artikel wegzulassen und sächliches Geschlecht anzunehmen.

Comment: Die Begründung 'wegen des Geschlechts' ist zirkulär. Die Vielzahl an Gegenbeispielen wirft die Frage auf, in wiefern das Ausnahmen sind. Und den Satz mit der Tendenz, bezieht sich der auch auf die Gegenbeispiele? Muss ja wohl, denn Wörter, die schon sächlich sind, können ja keine Tendenz haben sächlich zu werden. Also zunehmend werden auch Irak, Bahamas und Mongolei sächlich?

Comment: Das war keine Begründung, eher eine Erklärung: der weibliche Artikel wird eben für Länder, die ein Pluralwort enthalten, verwendet sowie für genuin weibliche Länder. Die "Vielzahl" der Gegenbeispiele ist, soweit ich das überblicke, erschöpfend. Bei knapp 200 Staaten, Nationen, Ländern oder Territorien darf man das also schon als Ausnahme bezeichnen. "Die Mongolei" wird man vielleicht noch länger hören, aber "ich fahre nach Irak" zB ist schon fast salonfähig.

Comment: Sind denn Deine Ausnahmen erschöpfend? Und genuin weibliche Länder sind weiblich, so wie genuin männliche Länder männlich sind und genuin sächliche sächlich? Gibt es auch Länder die weiblich sind, aber nicht genuin?

Comment: Die Argumentation ist verkehrt herum: Länderbezeichnungen haben ein Genus und einen Numerus; im Fall eines Neutrum Singular ohne Erweiterung wird kein Artikel benutzt, teilweise mit besonderen Konstruktionen (_nach Italien_, aber _in die Schweiz_, _ins Italien des vorigen Jahrhunderts_). – Übrigens war die Frage auf Englisch gestellt.

Comment: Ja, es gibt Länder die weiblich sind, weil sie einfach (auf deutsch) weibliche Namensbestandsteile enthalten (zB die Elfenbeinküste oder die Dominikanische Republik), oder im Plural verwendet werden (die Vereinigten Staaten, die Niederlande). Ansonsten ist meine Liste der Länder glaublich erschöpfend, wobei das natürlich nicht für alle Regionen und Landstriche gilt (die Wallachei und der Kosovo fallen mir hier noch spontan ein.) Hier gibt es aber auch Regionen, bei denen der sächliche Artikel geführt wird (das Burgenland, das Saarland, u. a. m.)

Comment: erschöpfend ist die Liste nicht, Oman ist oft genug noch maskulin. Historische Länder würden sicher auch vereinzelt noch dazukommen. Das nicht mehr produktive Landesnamensuffix -ei ist feminin, arabische Landesnamen wurden wohl häufig mitsamt Artikel übernommen, der maskulin blieb. Kongo und Niger wiederum sind nach Flüssen benannt, deren Genus übernommen wurde.

Comment: @Chieron Danke für den Hinweis auf den Oman, obwohl es sich dabei eher um süddeutschen Sprachgebrauch handelt habe ich in in die Liste aufgenommen.

Comment: @Ingmar: In deinen Kommentaren hat es den Anschein, als würden Länder mit Pluralbestandteilen als weibliche Substantive behandelt werden. Das stimmt natürlich nicht, sie werden als Pluralwörter behandelt.

Comment: Ja doch, und als solche bekommen sie den (Plural-)Artikel _die_. Das macht sie nicht weiblich, aber der verwendete Artikel ist der gleiche, dh insb nicht _der_ oder _das_.

Comment: @Ingmar : der Artikel verhält sich genauso, ist aber nur ein Homonym des weiblichen Artikels. Kleiner aber feiner Unterschied.

Comment: Just what I said.

Comment: Weitere Länder, die in der Liste fehlen:  der Senegal, der Gambia (seltener), die Komoren, (historisch) die Pfalz oder die Krim, das (Heilige) Römische Reich, die Tschechoslowakei. Interessant sind auch Doppelnamen wie *St. Vincent und die Grenadinen* oder *Bosnien-Herzegowina*, beide sächlich, aber gemischter Numerus/Genus.

Comment: @Ingmar es ist eben nicht derselbe Artikel, wenn er auch so aussieht. Aber das ist im wahrsten Sinne des Wortes Semantik. *Ja, es gibt Länder die weiblich sind, weil sie [..] im Plural verwendet werden [..]* ist bei einer Frage, die insbesondere Deutschlernende lesen sehr unglücklich.

Comment: Es gibt auch Plural ohne Artikel: Bosnien und Herzegowina, Serbien und Montenegro (nun nicht mehr), diverse Inselstaaten.

Comment: Das Niederland (sächlich) und Staat von Amerika (männlich), um die Frage weiterzuspielen, ob die Niederlande oder die USA weiblich sind. Man sieht aber, das beides quasi nie in Einzahl verwendet wird, d.h. es ist etwas wie eine geronnene Mehrzahl. Und historisch ist das Femininum wohl auch aus der Mehrzahl evolviert - die meisten Gruppen, die eine Vielzahl bezeichnen, ohne selbst Mehrzahl zu sein (Gruppe/Gruppen) sind weiblich: Gruppe, Versammlung, Band, Bürgerschaft, Bevölkerung, Familie, Verwandtschaft, ...

Answer (score 3):

All countries without article are neuter. So, *das.* (I've learned that from this [question here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9285/2014-spielt-deutschland-gegen-portugal-das-der-die-zu-stark-ist-wie-wah).)

Comment: *Bosnien und Herzegowina* sind... (und *die Herzegowina*). Außerdem gibt es Fälle wo Bundesrepublikaner und offizielle lokale Übersetzungen ins Deutsche keinen Artikel benutzen (zB Vojvodina), jedoch klingt es mir extrem blöd im nächsten Satz dann *das* statt *die heutige Vojvodina* zu sagen.

Comment: *Dänemark* müsste rein theoretisch auch so sein, ist aber nicht.

Comment: *Moldau* auch.  Wenige nutzen den Artikel, aber *die heutige Moldau* leistet dem neutralen Variant gute Konkurrenz.

Comment: @AdamM.B. Bezieht sich nicht aber *die Moldau* auf den Fluss?

Comment: Auch, in einer etwas anderen Ecke Europas von der Region Moldau und vom Land Moldawien bzw der Republik Moldau, und mit einer ganz anderen Etymologie die nur auf Deutsch zu verwechseln ist.  Also, ganz zufällig und unabhängig. :-)

Answer (score -3):

It is not true that countries with no article are neutral because in the sentence according to Dative declension it becomes (dem).

Ich komme aus Deutschland

If Deutschland was neutral it would be

Ich komme aus dem Deutschland

Because masculine and neutral uses the same article in Dative Declension.

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer. With sufficient reputation you will be able to comment everywhere. Also note that the observation is incorrect: *Ich komme aus dem schönen Deutschland.* In line with person names which *may* take articles but often don’t: *Das ist der lange Hans.*

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Unfortunately, I fail to follow your answer’s reasoning and do not see what your actual conclusion or answer to the question is. As far as I can see, your reasoning would apply analogously if countries were female. Please edit your answer to clarify.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Die Küche ist weiblich. Käme Santy aus der Küche wäre es 'der Küche' nicht 'dem Küche' (ich komme aus dem Wohnzimmer/dem Salon)/das Wohnzimmer, der Salon. Die Argumentation finde ich gut und einleuchtend.

Comment: @user unknown: *„Blick“ ist kein Maskulinum, denn sonst müßte es „Zimmer mit dem Blick aufs Meer“ heißen, nicht „mit Blick aufs Meer“.* Findest du diese Argumentation ebenfalls gut und einleuchtend?

Comment: @chirlu: Gehst Du zurück in Zimmer mit Blick auf einbeinige Analogien, die wo umfallen.