# Why do some but not all countries have articles?

Tags: article

I can't understand why some countries have articles. For example Switzerland is a word with an article: **Die Schweiz**. Why then do other countries (Großbritannien for example) not have articles?

Comment: See also http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10836/gender-of-country-names-without-articles

Comment: Hahah this question is what triggered my curiosity to add this! I'm looking for a more grammatical reason for the (or lack of) articles with countries!

Comment: Wenn man von Staaten weggeht, wird es sogar noch seltsamer: *England, Jütland* und *Helgoland,* aber *das Saarland, das Burgenland* und *das Emsland; Dänemark,* aber *die Steiermark* und *die Uckermark; der Selfkant …*

Comment: https://germanwordoftheday.de/countries-with-articles-in-german/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [Carsten Schultz](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10907/why-do-some-but-not-all-countries-have-articles/10909?noredirect=1#comment27592_10909)' comment, there are some rules:

1. Compound of common noun

   - Die Elfenbeinküste » Die **Küste**
   - Die Sowjetunion (or) Die UdSSR » Die **Union**
   - Die Zentralafrikanische Republik » Die **Republik**
   - Die Dominikanische Republik » Die **Republik**
   - Die Marshallinseln » Die **Insel**
   - Die Cookinseln » Die **Insel**
2. Plural

   - Die USA (or) Die Vereinigten Staaten von Amerika » Die **Staaten** (Plural of Staat)
   - Die Niederlande » Die **Lande** (Plural of *niederes Land*, an old German word)
   - Die Vereinigten Arabischen Emirate » Die **Emirate** (Plural of Emirat)
3. Article derived from long form to its short form

   - Die Philippinen » Die philipinischen **Inseln**
   - Die Salomonen » Die salomonischen **Inseln**
   - Die Malediven  » Die maledivischen **Inseln**
   - Die Komoren  » Die komorischen **Inseln**
   - Die Bahamas » Die [bahamischen](https://digital.slub-dresden.de/werkansicht/dlf/2049/62/) **Inseln**
   - Die Seychellen » Die [...] **Inseln**
   - Der Vatikan  » Der Staat Vatikanstadt » Der **Staat**
     <sup>[Official name in Germany is *Der Staat Vatikanstadt*  or *Staat der Vatikanstadt* (but also *Die Vatikanstadt*)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatikanstadt)</sup>
4. Transfer of landmarks on country name

   - Der Tschad » Country name derived from the lake *[Tschadsee](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tschadsee)* » Der **See**
   - Der Niger » Country name derived from the river *[Niger](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niger_(Fluss))* » Der **Fluss**
   - Der Senegal » Country name derived from the river *[Senegal](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senegal_(Fluss))* » Der **Fluss**
   - Der Kongo » Country name derived from the river *[Kongo](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kongo_(Fluss))* » Der **Fluss**
      <sup>According to [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demokratische_Republik_Kongo) *Der Kongo* refers to [Demokratische Republik Kongo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_Republic_of_the_Congo) and not to the state [Republik Kongo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_the_Congo)</sup>
5. Country name ending on *-ei*  (Not true for Brunei, which is still neutral)

   - Die Mongolei
   - Die Tschechei
   - Die Slowakei
   - Die Türkei
6. Without a rule

   - Der Iran » Empire de l'Iran  (mistranslation from french)
     <sup>[French was the official language for passes in Iran at the time where "Iran" as new country name was established](https://www.uni-marburg.de/de/cnms/iranistik)</sup>

---

<sup>Still unclear</sup>

- Die Ukraine
- Der Irak
- Der Jemen
- Der Libanon
- Der Sudan
- Der Kosovo
- Die Schweiz » Maybe from *Die Schweizerische Eidgenossenschaft* which is the [official name](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweiz)
  **or** maybe from *[Confoederatio Helvetica](http://official-name-abbreviations-meaning.all-about-switzerland.info/)* (feminine substantive in Latin)
  **or** maybe from *[Helvetia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetia)* which is (metaphorically) the female impersonation of Switzerland
  <sup>Read [Mathias Müller's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10907/why-do-some-but-not-all-countries-have-articles/10948#10948) from a historical point of view</sup>

---

The list considers only short forms of country names. Most official long forms contain their polity system like *Republik* [(129 of 196)](https://www.destatis.de/DE/Methoden/Klassifikationen/Bevoelkerung/Staatsangehoerigkeitsgebietsschluessel_xls.xlsx;jsessionid=CCA63A567D12F61C7EF444735977106A.cae2?__blob=publicationFile) or *Königreich*, and the article derives from that noun. As a result an article can differ between short and long form. For example it's "*Der* Kongo" (male) but "*Die* Demokratische Republik Kongo" (fem.)

### Further reading

- [Gender of country names without articles](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10836/gender-of-country-names-without-articles?lq=1)
- ["Iran" mit oder ohne Artikel?](https://www.uni-marburg.de/de/cnms/iranistik)
- [Etymologische Liste der Ländernamen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymologische_Liste_der_L%C3%A4ndernamen)
- [Im Iran oder in Iran? Ländernamen und der Artikel](http://canoonet.eu/blog/2009/08/21/im-iran-oder-in-iran-landernamen-und-der-artikel/)
- [Excel list of country names](https://www.destatis.de/DE/Methoden/Klassifikationen/Bevoelkerung/Staatsangehoerigkeitsgebietsschluessel_xls.xlsx;jsessionid=CCA63A567D12F61C7EF444735977106A.cae2?__blob=publicationFile) from the german Foreign Office
  <sup>(without article for short forms)</sup>
- [PDF list of country names](http://141.74.33.52/stagn/Portals/0/120403_STAATENNAMEN_12.pdf) from *[Ständiger Ausschuss für geopraphische Namen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%A4ndiger_Ausschuss_f%C3%BCr_geographische_Namen)*
  <sup>(with article for short forms)</sup>

Comment: Ok, +1, I see know it's possible to explain that :D ...wait, but "Kongo" has a *die* article (DRK), but its short name *(der) Kongo* has a masculine article.

Comment: "Die USA" sind nicht Femininum, sondern Maskulinum Plural. "Der Staat" -- "die Staaten".

Comment: @cp: they are two different states. thx elena, will be corrected

Comment: The article linked for *Iran* indeed does give some rules: Übertragungen von Namen anderer Dinge auf ein Land (z.B. "der Libanon" ursprünglich das Gebirge); Plural ("die Niederlande"); Zusammensetzungen mit Gattungsnamen ("die Sowjetunion") und Länder auf -ei ("die Türkei"). Of course the first one is hard to detect, but these cases seem to account for almost all of your examples. Btw, I see no reason to assume that the article of *Schweiz* has anything to do with *Eidgenossenschaft*.

Comment: +1 for your exhaustive answer - I added a tiny bit of info on Switzerland - perhaps you could remove it from "unclear" again? :-)

Answer (score 5):

A comprehensive list of explanations has been given already, I am just adding info on "die Schweiz" which has remained unclear in @nixda's answer and because it is part of the OP's question.

Bevor Aussagen über die Herkunft des femininen Geschlechts gemacht werden können, muss meiner Meinung nach der zeitliche Ablauf klar sein (Quelle: Historisches Lexikon der Schweiz, insbesondere [dieser Artikel](http://www.hls-dhs-dss.ch/textes/d/D9825.php)):

**10. Jahrhundert**

Es herrscht Konsens darüber, dass das Wort "Schweiz" auf den Kantonsnamen "Schwyz" zurückzuführen ist. Die erste schriftliche Erwähnung des Wortes ist schon 972 und meint die *Bevölkerung*, nicht einen Rechtsstaat oder ein Gebiet.

**16. bis 18. Jarhundert**

Der Begriff "Schweizerische Eidgenossenschaft" wird zum ersten Mal verwendet (vorher haben die Wörter unabhängig voneinander schon existiert). Seit 1803 ist "Schweizerische Eidgenossenschaft" eine offizielle Bezeichnung für die Schweiz.

**19. Jahrhundert**

Erst nach der Gründung des heutigen modernen Bundesstaates Schweiz (1848) wird "Confoederatio Helvetica" als Neolatinismus eingeführt.

---

**Erklärungen**

Die bisher genannten Erklärungen für den weiblichen Artikel des Wortes "Schweiz" sind:

1. "die Schweiz" ist eine Verkürzung von "die Schweizer Eidgenossenschaft" und übernimmt dessen weiblichen Artikel
2. "Schweiz" hat einen weiblichen Artikel weil der lateinische Begriff ("confoederatio") ein weibliches Substantiv ist
3. [Helvetia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetia), die weibliche Personifikation der Schweiz bestimmt das Geschlecht des heutigen Begriffs

---

**Beurteilung**

1. Der Begriff "Schweiz" ist einige Jahrhunderte älter als "Schweizerische Eidgenossenschaft". Deshalb denke ich, dass eine Beeinflussung unwahrscheinlich ist. Die beiden Begriffe können auch unabhängig voneinander den weiblichen Artikel angenommen haben.
2. Die lateinische Bezeichnung ist sehr spät entstanden und kann deswegen unmöglich den Artikel von "Schweiz" beeinflusst haben. Umgekehrt ist wohl anzunehmen, dass der weibliche Artikel von "Schweiz" den lateinischen Begriff sehr wohl beeinflusst hat.
3. Helvetia als weibliche Allegorie trat erstmals im 17. Jahrhundert in Erscheinung. Die Wahl einer weiblichen Identifikationsfigur könnte darauf hinweisen, dass die "Schweiz" seit jeher als etwas "weibliches" verstanden wurde. Andererseits haben andere Länder [ähnliche Figuren](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalallegorie), ohne dass der Artikel ihrer deutschen Landesbezeichnung feminin ist.

Comment: Wieso ist der Genus von *Confoederatio* relevant, der von *Eidgenossenschaft* aber nicht?

Comment: Wieso war *Schweiz* früher ohne Artikel? (Wobei man vorsichtig sein muss, welche Quellen sich auf die Eidgenossenschaft beziehen und welche auf den Kanton Schwyz, der immer noch ohne Artikel ist.)

Comment: Wieso hat es definitiv nichts mit *Eidgenossenschaft* zu tun? Immerhin ist *Die Schweizerische Eidgenossenschaft*  der amtliche Name in Deutschland. "Schweiz" könnte der Einfachkeit halber dem Volksmund entsprungen sein, weil der offizielle Name einfach unhandlich ist. Der Artikel könnte dann geblieben sein. Anyway, ich mag die Geschichtsstunde +1

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Nach reiflichem Nachforschen bin ich nun der Ansicht, dass meine Einschätzung des lateinischen Begriffs falsch ist. Der Begriff _Schweiz_ ist um einige hundert Jahre älter als _confoederatio h._ oder _Schweizerische Eidgenossenschaft_.

Comment: @nixda Das glaube ich eher weniger, siehe mein Kommentar oben zum Alter der drei Begriffe; _Schweiz_ ist älter als _Schweizerische Eidgenossenschaft_, kann also nicht eine kürzere Version davon sein. Sobald ich dazu komme, berichtige ich meine Antwort.

Comment: Super, dass Du Dir die Mühe gemacht hast. Die Erklärungen, die Du anbringst, überzeugen mich zwar auch erst einmal alle nicht (wegen genau des Grundes, den Du auch angibst, nämlich dass sich ähnliches auch von anderen Staaten sagen ließe, die aber dennoch keine Artikel tragen), aber das zeitliche Argument, mit dem Du sie verwirfst, ist auch nicht stichhaltig, ohne zu klären, [ab wann](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemid=GS21759) der Artikel benutzt wird.

Answer (score 1):

*This is an answer to object that there might not be a general answer.*

I don't know if there is a general answer. But I guess there are some of those exceptions which don't need an explanation: USA is, well, *die Vereinigten Staaten*, because its English name has plural.

But other explanations could be deep, interesting. Take for instance *die Ukraine*. Originally it comes [from *ukraina*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukraine), which means “border” (in English it's actually incorrect to say *the Ukraine*). So in German it bears an article perhaps because it wasn't lost departing from it's original meaning (*das Grenzgebiet*). This might be an explanation but only for this country. I think one should therefore explain why does *der Libanon*, *der Irak*, *die Schweiz* and so on have an article, departing form each country's etymology – which might deserve a huge answer.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside relevant to the original question, one issue is missing it seems to me: adjectives.
Just try any country name with „schöne“ in front.
Apparently any German proper and common noun accepts a definite article in combination with an adjective, same for relative clauses.
This means the article can be there, but most proper nouns – including most (all?) city names – are usually not combined with it.

This is another way to find out about gender by the way, in addition to pronominal reference.
„das schöne GB/UK“ -> das-Wort.