# Articles of the cities

Tags: article, grammaticality, standard-german

Which article should I use if I want to call a city beautiful? For example I want to say "Ich möchte das schöne Berlin mal besuchen."

> Is it "das schöne Berlin" oder "die schöne Berlin"? Or maybe "den schönen
>   Berlin"?

Berlin is just an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

„Das schöne Berlin“ is correct as well as „die schöne Stadt Berlin“. Berlin can be changed if neccessary.

But: „Das Dorf, die Gemeinde, der Ort“, if you want distinguish between city, town and village.

Answer (score 1):

Most towns/cities, countries and continents are neuter (*das*).

There are a few exceptions e.g.:

> die Schweiz, die Türkei, die Slowakei
>   der Libanon, der Jemen
>   die Niederlande (*plural*)

There's a more complete list of the exceptions [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10907/why-do-some-but-not-all-countries-have-articles)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that saying : "Ich möchte die schöne Stadt Berlin besichtigen" is correct. When I went to Germany one year ago I heard many people saying sentences like this one with other city names!

Comment: You are correct, one could say '_due schöne Stadt Berlin_'. However, the question was about the article if the noun _Stadt_ is omitted: is it _der/die/das schöne Berlin_?  Maybe you can edit your answer to add this.

Comment: _due_ should be _die_